# Unix FIND command in Groovy

Tags: unix, groovy, scripting, ksh, groovy-console

I am working on converting a KornShell (ksh) script to Groovy. I have the following Find command - what would be a Groovy way to do something similar, without relying on Unix commands (I need this to work cross-platform, so I can not do a "blah blah".execute()).

```
find <source directory> -name <file pattern> -type f -mtime +140 -level 0
```

This code searches for all files in the source directory (no subdirs) that match a file pattern and are older than 140 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groovy provides some methods for searching through directories: [`File.eachFile`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure)) for the `-level 0` case, or [`File.eachFileRecurse`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileRecurse(groovy.lang.Closure)) for the general case.  Example:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    new File(".").eachFile { file ->
        if (file.isFile() &&
            file.lastModified() < (new Date() - 140.days).time) {
            println file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or if you're doing level 0, you could do File.listFiles() and follow that with findAll to just get the old files into a collection

Comment: The asker also wanted to match name against a pattern which needs to use eachFileMatch() such as new File('.').eachFileMatch(~/.*?\.JPG/) {...